# How can I scale my font with different types of screen?

Tags: java, android

I have made an Android application, but it must work on different types of screen, and I have done that too. But it is 1 thing - for creating scaling screen I use layout_weight and dp instead px. But how can I scale my fonts in .xml files? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

use `android:textSize = "10sp"` , `sp` will scale fonts similar to dp.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **sp** : [scale independent pixels](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension)

```
sp :Scale-independent Pixels - this is like the dp unit, but it is also scaled
by the  user's font size preference. It is recommend you use this unit when 
specifying font sizes, so they will be adjusted for both the screen density and 
the user's preference.
```